# How do I get a counter for an "each" loop in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I add a counter to an `.each` loop? Is there any easy way of doing this?
I tried the below, but it does not seem to work.

```
<% @album.each do |e| %>
   <%= e %> #my_counter_does_not_work :)
   <%= link_to e.name, :controller => "images", :action => "album", :album_id => e.id, :album_name => e.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: are you trying to loop through a list? is @album a list of something? by it's naming it seems to be a single object, which you can't iterate over because a single object is not iterable by default. A tad more information here would help diagnose your issue better.

Comment: @album is a list of albums from db

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `each_with_index` : the index will automatically be your counter (but note it starts at 0 and not 1):

```
<% @album.each_with_index do |e, index| %>
  <%= link_to e.name, :controller => "images", :action => "album", :album_id => e.id, :album_name => e.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As of ruby 1.9.1 you can chain a `.with_index` on every method that returns an Enumerator to get the same result. You can also supply an integer as an argument to represent the starting index, if this for some reason shouldn't be 0.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Enumerable#each_with_index

http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index